# GNU Linking and Compiling

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries, gnu, static-linking

So I'm trying to create a library of source files that must be linked to other libraries.  My make file looks like

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -static -std=c99 -I "./include/ImageMagick-6/"
MAGICKLIB=-Llib -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16
INCLUDE=-lfreetype -ljpeg -lfontconfig -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -lpng -lgomp -lpthread -lltdl
LINK=$(INCLUDE) $(MAGICKLIB)
COMMON=setUp.o closeOut.o readImage.o writeImage.o edgeEnhance.o resizeImage.o

lib: $(COMMON)
        ar -cvq libmyip.a $(COMMON)

setUp.o: setUp.c myip.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c setUp.c $(LINK)

closeOut.o: closeOut.c myip.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c closeOut.c $(LINK)

readImage.o: readImage.c myip.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c readImage.c $(LINK)

writeImage.o: writeImage.c myip.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c writeImage.c $(LINK)

edgeEnhance.o: edgeEnhance.c myip.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c edgeEnhance.c $(LINK)

resizeImage.o: resizeImage.c myip.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c resizeImage.c $(LINK)

myIPTest.o: myIPTest.c myip.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c myIPTest.c $(LINK)

myIPTest: myIPTest.o myip.h libmyip.a
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myIPTest myIPTest.o -Llib -lmyip
```

Running make I get no errors/warnings.  I am getting unrecognized reference when I run make myIPTest.  I think it might be because the .o targets (setUp.o etc) are not linking the .c files properly?  I'm not sure though. I'm a noob, I've been searching the internet for hours and I can't seem to fix it.  Any of you guys have any ideas?

FIXED: Removed all the $(LINK) from my .o targets and just put it at the end of myIPTest target and it worked.

Comment: Which references are undefined? Can you include the actual error messages?

Comment: Have you thought about using GNU autotools? that's what most GNU software uses for building.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile source files to object files with `-c` option, all `-lsomelibrary` options are useless. These options only work when the compiler links object files into an executable file.

In other words, `$(LINK)` should be added to the last action line in your makefile (the one which builds `myIPTest`); in all the other lines it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

`-Llib` instructs the linker to look for `libmyip.a` in a `lib` directory. On the other hand, the `lib` rule creates `libmyip.a` in the current directory. Replace `-Llib` with `-L.` and see what happen.

PS: the rest of makefile needs some refactoring as well.

Comment: The -Llib includes current directory as well.  What kind of refactoring would you suggest?

Comment: No it doesn't. Did you try explicit `-L`? BTW, where `libmyip.a` is actually located? Let's solve the problem first, and discuss makefile refactoring later. PPS: as Alexey Kukanov mentioned, the $(LINK) options are a must for `myIPTest` rule. Sorry I didn't notice.